# prime numbers program gives wrong answer

Tags: go

I recently created a program which will tell you if a number is prime or not. It gets all answers right but the prime number of 9.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func isPrime(num int) bool {
    for x := 2; x > 1; x++ {
        if num%2 == 0 {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("is it a prime number: %v \n", isPrime(9))
}
```

What is the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, seems to me `isPrime` will return true for all odd numbers and false for all even numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Here is the working version of your code: try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gFGlQiUFJE).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func isPrime(num int) bool {
    if num < 2 {
        return false
    }
    for x := 2; x < num; x++ {
        if num%x == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("is it a prime number: %v \n", isPrime(9))
}
```

---

2- The only even prime is 2, so it is better to check it first:

```
if n == 2 {
    return true
}
```

Then there is no other even prime number: remove them all, and there is no prime number less than 2:

```
if n < 2 || n&1 == 0 {
    return false
}
```

and you don't need to check more than square root of `n`:

```
sqrt := int(math.Sqrt(float64(n)))
```

And now you may start from 3, with just odd numbers (`i += 2`):

```
for i := 3; i <= sqrt; i += 2 {
    if n%i == 0 {
        return false
    }
}
```

Try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8UhlNO7u4e):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func isPrime(n int) bool {
    if n == 2 {
        return true
    }
    if n < 2 || n&1 == 0 {
        return false
    }
    sqrt := int(math.Sqrt(float64(n)))
    for i := 3; i <= sqrt; i += 2 {
        if n%i == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("is it a prime number: %v \n", isPrime(9))
    for i := 0; i < 120; i++ {
        if isPrime(i) {
            fmt.Print(i, " ")
        }
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

output:

```
is it a prime number: false 
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113
```

---

See:
[Prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)
[Generating primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it is, your code is only checking if a number's parity and returning false if it is even. I don't actually know Go, but I did manage to work out this problem for you using the following code:

```
func isPrime(num int) bool {
    for x := 2; x < num; x++{
        if num%x == 0 && num!=2{
            return false
        }
    }return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [prime number definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) *A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself*, in your code you're only checking if it's **odd** or not.

I left you a fast solution in Go https://play.golang.org/p/2XXTUFbjhy It does only go until the square root of the number.

```
func isPrime(n int) bool {
    if n <= 1 {
        return false
    }
    for ix, sqn := 2, int(math.Sqrt(float64(n))); ix <= sqn; ix++ {
        if n%ix == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Also if you're interested in a faster way to know if a number is primer or not I recommend you read about the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)